# PHP Blowfish File Missing?

Tags: php, pear, blowfish

I am testing Blowfish on the RHEL Server. But having followng error:

```
Failed opening required 'Blowfish/DefaultKey.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/..........
```

`Blowfish/DefaultKey.php` file is missing? How to install it?

Comment: Try [the following](http://bit.ly/106p6P8).

Comment: Where is that file supposed to come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the full path of the file: `Crypt/Blowfish/DefaultKey.php`